# Why simple exit program do not work?

Tags: linux, assembly, syntax, x86, gnu-assembler

I am new to assembly language programming. I write following code,

```
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl $1,%eax
    movl $0,%ebx
    int $0x80
```

and use `as -o JustExit.o JustExit.asm` command for creating object file. (Assembly file name is JustExit.asm).

After this step I gave executable permission using,

> chmod 777 ./JustExit.o

When I execute program it says,

> -su: ./JustExit.o: cannot execute binary file

I am not able to understand why this simple 'exit' program is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assembling your source through `as` produces an [object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) which is "not yet" executable.
You have to link the object file with a [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) such as `ld`, which will then produce a fully working executable (`a.out` by default).

Your command line chain would look like this:

```
$ as -o JustExit.o JustExit.asm
$ ld JustExit.o
$ ./a.out
```

And it works!